# Posicionar divs sólo con la propiedad position

Tags: css

Estoy haciendo experimentos con CSS y quiero posicionar una estructura correctamente sólo utilizando la propiedad `position`, sin utilizar float, ni flexbox, ni grid. Os dejo la estructura a ver si me podéis echar un cable...

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="main">
  <div id="menu"></div>
  <div id="content"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Simple, una cabecera, un main con dos divs en su interior (menu y content), y un footer. Los elementos dentro del main (menu y content) quiero que se posicionen uno al lado del otro perfectamente, tanto si tienen contenido dentro, como si no.

Estoy intentando profundizar en la maquetación web sin utilizar técnicas actuales y avanzadas, como flexbox o grid.

Comment: ¿Y qué has intentado al momento?

Comment: body{
    margin: 0px;
}

div{
    min-height: 200px;
}

#header, #main, #footer{
    background-color: #333;
}

#footer{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}

#menu{
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    width: 30%;
}

#content{
    position: absolute;
    left: 30%;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: lightgray;
    width: 70%;
}

Pero la altura del #menu y el #content no se ajusta al total del espacio que queda entre #header y #footer

Comment: Esos detalles deben ir en la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Hola @Hugo pude llegar a una resolución de lo que buscabas hacer.

E puesto a los 2 elementos como absolutos y les he asignado un ancho en pixeles, como ambos son absolutos por default se encimarán uno del otro, para poder separarlos a uno le proporciono en pixeles, también, que tanto debería de estar a la derecha. Te dejo el ejemplo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        #header {
            border: 1px solid black;
            height: 89px;
        }
        #main {
            border: 1px solid red;
            height: 100vh;
        }
        #menu {
            font-weight: bold;
            position: absolute;
            width: 233px;
            border: 1px solid blue;
        }
        #content {
            background-color: grey;
            color: white;
            padding: 8px;
            position: absolute;
            width: 233px;
            right: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="menu">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit.
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi delectus velit numquam labore consectetur ducimus, nostrum blanditiis ut iste quidem?
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>

</body>
</html>
```